# Two post types with same single template

Tags: custom-post-types

I have two custom post types, their slugs are: `slug-a` and `slug-b`.

I have created two identical single template: `single-slug-a.php` and `single-slug-b.php`.

This obviously works as expected.

Is there any way to create just one PHP file for both my post types (ex. `single-slug-a-and-slug-b.php`)?

---

**SOLUTION:**

I've found this solution:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) 
{
    // your custom post types
    $my_types = array( 'slug-a', 'slug-b' );
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if ( ! in_array( $post_type, $my_types ) )
        return $template;

    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-my-template.php'; 
});
```

Is there a more correct way?

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to create the template as a Page Template, and have both CPTs support `page-attributes` so they can then use Page Templates.

Typically you name the template something like `tpl-yourname.php` and it would contain a comment at the top:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Your Name
* Template Post Type: cpt-slug-a, cpt-slug-b
*
```

The template name will be what you see in the dropdown menu when you are editing one of the CPTs. The template post type needs to contain the names of the post types - i.e. a WP Core Post you would specify as "post" and a CPT called Portfolio you would specify as "portfolio".

You also have to tell each CPT to support `page-attributes` so that the editor will show the template dropdown.

```
register_post_type('cpt-slug-a',
    // lots of other code here
    // this just shows the line you need to add "page-attributes" to
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes');
    // lots of other code here
);
```

Just add `page-attributes` to the array, leaving whatever other things your CPTs support.

As to which way is "correct," I think that's a matter of preference. To me personally this way of using Page Templates seems a little more flexible, since non-technical people can then easily apply the template to whatever pages they like in the editor, and your original way requires coding to apply the template to any additional pages.